# SQL - Selecting items from table based on data in other tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

[image: Relational Schema Image]

In the above relational schema, how would I do the following?:

List the names of all students that have a higher GPA than the minimum required GPA for the major they have applied for.

Comment: Is this a home work question or jobinterview question? If so read "how do i ask home work questions" https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: `JOIN` is the keyword you're looking for

Comment: "I have attempted it many times".  So...where's the attempt???  I don't see it.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work? ...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/271271)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use JOIN and NATURAL JOIN(this one is not required but i like it),
with join you ufse 2 tables giving 2 columns that need to be equal(you specify them in the WHERE), NATURAL JOIN does the same but assuming you have 1 or more columns with the same name(those are the ones natural join uses like if they were delared in the where)

So first you fuse MinimumGPA and Apply(they have 2 cols with the same name so natural join)

```
Select * FROM MinimumGPA NATURAL JOIN Apply
```

then, since you awhere asked for the NAMES of the students, you fuse that new table(giving it a name, in this case i used MinimumGPAApply, you could name it "the dogtable" if you wanted) with students, since the name on the columns isnt the same you use JOIN and specify the columns in the where, also you add the gpa condition

```
Select sName from Student JOIN (The first query) As MinimumGPAApply WHERE Student.sId = MinimumGPAApply.sID AND Student.GPA > MinimumGPAApply.minGPA
```

So at the end you end with somethign like this:

```
Select sName from Student JOIN (Select * FROM MinimumGPA NATURAL JOIN Apply) As MinimumGPAApply WHERE Student.sId = MinimumGPAApply.sID AND Student.GPA > MinimumGPAApply.minGPA
```

Comment: For that you fuse Apply and Student, and use the word COUNT to count the amount of rows, but that alone will just give you the total of apply rows, since you want them by student you use "GROUP BY", So, "Select Name,Count From (Select sId, COUNT(sId) FROM Apply GROUP BY sID ) JOIN Student  WHERE Student.sId = Apply .sID something like that

Comment: You are doing count(*) in the select  student, there is always gonna be only 1 student of each, lookinto the sql i posted, in the outter select i didnt use the function count, i selected the count i had already done inside the other select, BTW you should post this in a diferent question, comments aren suposed to be used for this (also since your original question was answered[by multiple ppl] you should select an answer

Comment: Sorry, im used to postgresql and the column name changes sometimes, just run the inner query so you can see what name is being given to the column with the count, remember, its always easier to do SQL queries, step by step, subQuery by subQuery, so, run just the inner one, and see the looks of the table you are given, with that, you can build the bigger query around the resuts you observed

Answer (score 2):

A couple of joins should do the trick:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM   Student s
JOIN   Apply a ON s.sId = a.sId
JOIN   MinimumGPA m on m.major = a.major
WHERE  s.gpa > m.mingpa
```

Comment: A couple of explanation would be better.

Comment: Yes if you could explain how this works then that would be very useful!

Comment: it should be `s.gpa > m.mingpa` by the way "List the names of all students that have a **higher** GPA than the minimum required GPA for the major they have applied for."

Comment: the best explainment is here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html @yoyo1 .. Simply said the JOIN clause merge and can filter two tables together.

Answer (score 0):

```
select s.Cname,s.gpa as studentGpa ,mg.mingpa as mingpaRequired from student s
inner join apply a on   s.sid=a.sid
inner join major m on m.major=a.major
inner join minimumGPA mg on mg.major=m.major
where  mg.mingpa<s.gpa
```